# ¿Cómo uso OnPointerEnter en Unity para cambiar el color de un objeto?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Tengo que programar en unity para un trabajo de la universidad y nunca lo hice, por lo que estoy aprendiendo todo por internet.

Lo que tengo que hacer es un jueguito donde al pasar el mouse por encima de los objetos, estos cambien de color (y queden así).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve investigando y descubrí que podía usar EventTrigger, más específicamente OnPointerEnter, pero no se como programarlo. Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y otras secciones que aparecen en la misma página [como donde se pide que pongas tu código de intento](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2875#2875). Después vienes, editas tu pregunta y seguro que la comunidad estará más interesada en ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un script y asignarselo al objeto que quieres que cambie de color, despues al objeto le agregas el componente EventTriger y agregas el evento onpointerenter en el apartado debajo de runtimer asignas el mismo objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues en el script agregas estas lineas de codigo:

```
public class CambiarColor : MonoBehaviour
{

Image Imagen;

private void Start()
{
    Imagen = GetComponent<Image>();
}
public void CambiarDeColor()
{
    Imagen.color = Color.black; //Aqui pones el color que quieras
}
}
```

ahora ya solo asignamos la funcion al evento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]